# Как вывести адаптер БД из активити в lisfragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести адаптер БД в listfragment?

Есть такой код активности.

```
@SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etKolvo.getText().

                    toString())) {
                return;
            }

            int kolvo = (int) Float.parseFloat(etKolvo.getText().toString());

            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnRaschet:
                    break;
            }
            try {
                db = FirstDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                int Wid = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_WID);

               cursor = db.rawQuery("select _id, COL1, COL2, COL3, (COL3 * " + kolvo + ") as MASSA " +
                     "from TABLE where TYPE = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(wid)});
```

Как вынести только адаптер БД в listfragment?

```
public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                inflater.getContext(),
                R.layout.my_view,
//а здесь я не знаю как сослаться на бд
                new String[]{"COL1","MASSA"},
                new int[]{R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2},
                0);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Непонятно что у вас за архитектура. При нажатии кнопки фрагмент уже отображается или создаётся? Почему обработчик кнопки в активности, а не в самом фрагменте?

Comment: Да фрагмент уже отображён, а в кнопке всё и дело. Сам фрагмент это нижняя часть активности и в нём должны выводится только данные БД(там дальше ещё вкладки идут). Вот я и хочу (если так можно) перенести в фрагмент только адаптер, а курсор оставить в активности. –